# Mutually recursive types in OCaml

Tags: haskell, recursion, ocaml, algebraic-data-types, mutual-recursion

In Haskell you can do the following:

```hs
Prelude> data Foo = Foo Bar; data Bar = Bar Foo
```

How can you do the same thing in OCaml? I tried:

```ml
                    ___
# type foo = Foo of bar;; type bar = Bar of foo;;
Error: Unbound type constructor bar
```

Is it even possible to define mutually recursive data types in OCaml? If not then why?

Comparing data definitions to let expressions: mutually recursive data types correspond to using `let rec` (or more appropriately `type rec` for want of a better phrase). What are the advantages of being able to define mutually recursive data types? My foobar example is trivial. Can you think of any non-trivial uses of mutually recursive data types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ivg` answered your question, but here's a non-trivial mutually recursive type.

```ml
module Stream = struct

  type 'a t    = unit -> 'a node
   and 'a node = Nil
               | Cons of 'a * 'a t 

end
```

This is the genuine type of spine-lazy streams. That said, you could construct it without mutually recursive types

```ml
type 'a t = Stream of (unit -> ('a * 'a t) option)
```

Offhand my thought is that you can always reduce a family of mutually recursive types into a single one if you like (though perhaps not in OCaml—the encoding I'm thinking of would make non-trivial use of dependent type indices), but it can certainly be more clear directly.

Comment: actually, your second type definition doesn't work, it will say that type definition is cyclic. The correct way would be `type 'a t = Stream of (unit -> ('a * 'a t) option)`

Comment: Oh, whoops! Yep, didn't check it in the interpreter. Fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Use `and`

```
type foo = Foo of bar
 and bar = Bar of foo
```

Comment: Explicit mutual recursion. I like that more than the Haskell syntax. Explicit is always better than implicit.

Comment: It's actually annoyingly slightly less than totally explicit. What would be maximally explicit would be `type rec foo = Foo of bar and bar = Bar of foo`. You run into (small) issues when, for instance, there's an ambient type `t` and you'd like to make a new type `t` in a submodule which aliases the ambient `t`, but `type t module X = struct type t = t end` is an error because it assumes you mean to construct the infinite type `type x = x`.

Comment: there is an interesting several years [discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6623) on this topic, that results in a new `nonrec` keyword. In 4.03 we will have `type nonrec t` and even (I'm not sure whether it ended up in the final patch) `type rec t`.

Comment: So `type rec` is still the default? You can just add the declaration to be extra explicit?